# Canceling zero while evaluating a limit

Tags: calculus, limits

I am extremely sorry if my title doesn't actually matches with the question that i have asked. I was solving a limit. It was as follows:

We are given that $ \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x) - 5}{x-2} = 3$ and we have to find   $\lim_{x \to 2}f(x)$. I did this:

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{f(x) - 5}{(x-2)} = 3$$
$$\implies \frac{\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) -5}{\lim_{x \to 2}(x-2)} = 3$$
$$\implies \frac{\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) -\lim_{x \to 2}5}{\lim_{x \to 2}(x-2)} = 3$$
$$\implies \frac{\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) -\lim_{x \to 2}5}{\lim_{x \to 2}(x-2)}*\lim_{x \to 2}(x-2) = 3*\lim_{x \to 2}(x-2) $$
$$\implies \lim_{x \to 2} f(x) -\lim_{x \to 2}5 = 3*\lim_{x \to 2}(x-2)$$
$$\implies \lim_{x \to 2} f(x) -5 = 3*0$$
$$\implies \lim_{x \to 2} f(x) -5 = 0$$
$$\implies \lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 5$$

and the answer matched with the answer given. But in step $4$, I canceled $ \lim_{x \to 2}(x-2)$ which actually zero. So I don't think that I can do this. Still I found the answer. Is my method right then how is it? and if wrong , is there any other method to find this limit?

Comment: Better write the limit outside the expression, then you can cancel the factor out and take the limit after this has been done. In fact as written, you divided by zero.

Comment: You can cancel out the $x-2$ - factors as long as they are not $0$

Comment: but here i am not canceling $x-2$ but the limit of x- 2 as x approaches 2

Comment: And this is in fact not correct since this limit is $0$. The limit law with the quotient can only be applied if the denominator does not tend to $0$.

Comment: @Peter yeah, you are right. I forgot that condition.

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that this is, in some sense, "obvious," because if the limit of $f(x)$ was anything other than 5, then the limit you started with would blow up to infinity or negative infinity (because the numerator would be nonzero) instead of being equal to three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to give a valid justification, you must correctly apply the theorems on limits. To start with, here are two limits that you know are true: the first is known by hypothesis; and the second is probably already well known to you:
$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x)-5}{x-2} = 3 \qquad\lim_{x \to 2} (x-2) = 0
$$
Now apply the following theorem on limit of a product:

> **Theorem:** If $\lim_{x \to a} g(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a} h(x)$ both exist then $\lim_{x \to a} (g(x) \cdot h(x))$ exists and
> $$\lim_{x \to a} (g(x) \cdot h(x)) = \bigl( \lim_{x \to a} g(x) \bigr) \cdot \bigl(\lim_{x \to a} h(x) \bigr)
> $$

Applying this theorem using $g(x) = \frac{f(x)-5}{x-2}$ and $h(x)=x-2$, whose limits as $x \to 2$ are known to exist, you may conclude that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 2} (f(x)-5) &= \lim_{x \to 2} \left( \frac{f(x)-5}{x-2} \cdot (x-2) \right) \\
&= \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{f(x)-5}{x-2}  \cdot \lim_{x \to 2} (x-2) \\
&= 3 \cdot 0 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}
Then, knowing that $\lim_{x \to 2} (f(x)-5)=0$, it is a small step to conclude that $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x)=5$ (you can fully justify **that** step by applying the theorem on limit of a sum).

Comment: I assume your theorem meant to say: $$\lim_{x\to a}(g(x)\cdot h(x))$$

Comment: Oops, yes, thanks for the correction.